# How to update only selected records in lightningdatatable using inline editing in LWC component

Tags: lightning-datatable, inline-editing

I am new to LWC and trying to achieve the update functionality for only selected rows on lightningDataTable. Normal update I am able to do but once I edited the fields for multiple rows and then I wants to select some row using checkbox on ligtningDataTable to keep the changes and get updated on click of save button but if no checkbox is selected then it will save all the edited records. Thanks in Advance.

My Code:

HTML:

```
<template>
    <lightning-card variant="Narrow" title="Custom Comp" icon-name="custom:custom11">
        <div class="slds-var-m-around_medium">
         
            <lightning-datatable 
                data-id="table" 
                key-field="Id" 
                data={data} 
                columns={columns} 
                onrowselection ={onRowSelection} 
                selected-rows={allSelectedRows} 
                onsave={handleSave}
                draft-values={saveDraftValues}>
           </lightning-datatable>
           </br>
        </div>
    </lightning-card>
</template>
```

JS:

```
import { LightningElement, wire, api, track} from 'lwc';
import { updateRecord } from 'lightning/uiRecordApi';
import { ShowToastEvent } from 'lightning/platformShowToastEvent';
import { refreshApex } from '@salesforce/apex';
import getChilds from '@salesforce/apex/CustomRelatedListController.getChilds';


export default class LightningDatatableProject extends LightningElement {
    
    @track value;
    @track error;
    @track data;        
    @api recordId;    
    @api childObjName;
    @api fields;
    @api parentFieldAPIName; 
    @api tableColumns;
    @track recordsCount = 0;    
    @track items = []; 
    @track data = [];      
    @track columns;
    wiredForRefresh;
    result;
    isPageChanged = false;
    initialLoad = true;
    mapoppNameVsOpp = new Map();
    saveDraftValues = [];    
    selectedRecords = []; 


    get loadFields() {  
        return this.childObjName + '-' + this.parentFieldAPIName + '-' + this.tableColumns + '-' + this.fields;               
    }


    connectedCallback(){
        this.columns = JSON.parse( this.tableColumns.replace( /([a-zA-Z0-9]+?):/g, '"$1":' ).replace( /'/g, '"' ) );
    }
  
    //Calling the apex method and passing the parameters.
    @wire(getChilds, {recordId: '$recordId', payload: '$loadFields'})
    wiredRecord(value){
        this.wiredForRefresh = value;
        const { data, error } = value; 
        if (data) {
            this.items = data;
            this.processRecords(data);
            this.error = undefined;
        } else if (error) {
            this.error = error;
            this.data = undefined;
        }
    }
      

    //This function is to handles the update record on click of save button.
    handleSave(event) {
        this.saveDraftValues = event.detail.draftValues;
        const recordInputs =  this.saveDraftValues.slice().map(draft => {
            const fields = Object.assign({}, draft);
            return { fields };
        });
    
        const promises = recordInputs.map(recordInput => updateRecord(recordInput));
        Promise.all(promises).then(res => {
            this.dispatchEvent(
                new ShowToastEvent({
                    title: 'Success',
                    message: 'Records Updated Successfully!!',
                    variant: 'success'
                })
            );              
             // Display fresh data in the datatable
            return refreshApex(this.wiredForRefresh);
        }).catch(error => {
             this.dispatchEvent(
                new ShowToastEvent({
                   title: 'Error updating or reloading record',
                   message: error.body.message,
                   variant: 'error'
                })
             );
        }).finally(() => {
            this.saveDraftValues = [];
        });
    }

    processRecords(data){        
        this.data = data;
    }
            
    //This method gets the selected records    
    onRowSelection(event){
        const selectedRows = event.detail.selectedRows;
        this.recordsCount = event.detail.selectedRows.length;
        this.selectedRecords=new Array();
        for (let i = 0; i < selectedRows.length; i++) {
            this.selectedRecords.push(selectedRows[i]);
        }           
    }
}
```

Apex:

```
public with sharing class CustomComp {

    @AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
    public static List<sObject> getChilds(String recordId,String payload) {

     String childObjectName = '';
     String parentField = '';
     String fields = '';
     String query = '';

     //Spliting the payload coming from lwc properties. 
     childObjectName = payload.split('-')[0];
     parentField = payload.split('-')[1];
     fields = payload.split('-')[3];
 
     //Null check for incoming field values.
     if( String.isBlank(childObjectName) || String.isBlank(parentField)){
         throw new AuraHandledException('Child Object or Parent Relationship Field is missing.');
     }
     else{      
         if(!String.isBlank(fields)){ 
           query = 'Select id,Name,' + fields + ' FROM ' + childObjectName + ' Where ' + parentField + ' = \'' + recordId + '\'';
        }     
        else{
            query = 'Select id,Name' + ' FROM ' + childObjectName + ' Where ' + parentField + ' = \'' + recordId + '\'';
         }
     }
        return Database.query( query );
    }

}
```